Why is the menu overlapping the hamburger icon?
I created a simple hamburger menu. The base layout of the website needs to use grid. The menu works fine, but when you reduce the browser window size and the hamburger icon appears, clicking on it causes the menu to overlap the bottom half of the hamburger icon.


"use strict";

// Hamburger navigation
const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
});
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "nav"
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  position: relative;
}

/* Hamburger icon */
.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}

/* Hamburger animation */
.nav.open .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Dropdown */
.menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-menu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu > li + li {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: .8em .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.open .menu-dropdown {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 800px);
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .tags {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-dropdown {
    position: initial;
    overflow: initial;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-menu > li + li {
    margin-left: 2.3em;
    border-top: initial;
  }

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-dropdown">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- / .menu-dropdown -->
    </nav> <!-- / .nav -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>



Any idea what might be causing the menu to cover half of the hamburger icon? I spent over half an hour trying different options, but I couldn't figure it out. The menu should open right below the hamburger icon.
Here's another version which works:


"use strict";

// Hamburger navigation
const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
});
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Hamburger icon */
.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}

/* Hamburger animation */
.nav.open .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Dropdown */
.menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-menu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu > li + li {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: .8em .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.open .menu-dropdown {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .logo {
    position: initial;
    transform: initial;
  }

  .menu-dropdown {
    position: initial;
    overflow: initial;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-menu > li + li {
    margin-left: 2.3em;
    border-top: initial;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav-simple.css">
  <title>Hamburger Navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">

      <!-- Site logo -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Site navigation -->
      <nav class="nav">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-dropdown">
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- / .menu-dropdown -->
      </nav> <!-- / .nav -->
    </div> <!-- / .header-container -->
  </header>

  <script src="nav-simple.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



Considering that this second version works, does it may have to do with grid in the first code?

Without changing your current layout, it can be fixed by adding the z-index property on the .menu-toggle.
.menu-toggle {
    z-index: 50;
}

Old JSFiddle Demo

Update


"use strict";

// Hamburger navigation
const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
});
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "nav";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.menu-toggle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100; 
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}

.nav.open .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav.open .hamburger::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; 
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-menu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-menu > li + li {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.open .menu-dropdown {
  max-height: 300px;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 800px);
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .tags {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-dropdown {
    position: initial;
    overflow: initial;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-menu > li + li {
    margin-left: 2.3em;
    border-top: initial;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-dropdown">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- / .menu-dropdown -->
    </nav> <!-- / .nav -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>




Yes, that shows the hamburger icon, but the menu list should be below the icon.

Hello. Thank you. I appreciate your time. Please check out the second version. I updated the original post.  Why it doesn't happen in that? And I don't have any margin or z-index?

The second example uses flexbox instead of grid. Is it working as you want it to?

The second works, but I need the first to work with grid.

Thank you so much. I appreciate your help. I'll check the code tomorrow since it's late night here and I'll mark your answer as the best.

Try adding something like a margin-top: 20px; to your menu-dropdown class yet.

To answer your newer question, you changed the height to the element that holds the hamburger button (Never phrased it like that. That's smart). Changing the height pushed the menu element down.

Hello. Thank you. I appreciate your time. Please check out the second version. I updated the original post.  Why it doesn't happen in that? And I don't have any lowering?

@ZoltanKing Please avoid changing questions in a way that invalidates answers
